# How to use multiple xpath datasets on XML datasource using PHP Jasper?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, jasper-reports

I have designed a report in Jasper Studio that use XML as datasource and two XPATH datasets. I am able to generate the report and the data is filled from the first dataset (/data/invoice), but the second dataset (/data/invoice_items/row) is not found and returns null.

How can I add a second xpath to the php script for 'xml_xpath' => `'/data/invoice_items/row'`

**This is my XML data:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <invoice>
        <ID_Invoice>54654</ID_Invoice>
        <Invoice_Code>FCS</Invoice_Code>
        <Invoice_No>1</Invoice_No>
        <Invoice_Date>09/08/2019</Invoice_Date>
        <Seller_Name>Seller</Seller_Name>
        <Seller_VAT_Code>123123</Seller_VAT_Code>
        <Seller_Adress>New York</Seller_Adress>
        <Seller_Email/>
        <Partner_Name>John</Partner_Name>
        <Partner_VAT_Code>123456789</Partner_VAT_Code>
        <Partner_Adress>Atlanta</Partner_Adress>
        <Partner_Email/>
    </invoice>
    <invoice_items>
        <row>
            <ID_Invoice_Row>29433</ID_Invoice_Row>
            <Denumire>Product 1</Denumire>
            <Valoare>555.0000</Valoare>
            <VAT>0.0000</VAT>
            <TOTAL>555.0000</TOTAL>
        </row>
        <row>
            <ID_Invoice_Row>42345</ID_Invoice_Row>
            <Denumire>Product 2</Denumire>
            <Valoare>555.0000</Valoare>
            <VAT>0.0000</VAT>
            <TOTAL>555.0000</TOTAL>
        </row>
        <row>
            <ID_Invoice_Row>11234</ID_Invoice_Row>
            <Denumire>Product 3</Denumire>
            <Valoare>555.0000</Valoare>
            <VAT>0.0000</VAT>
            <TOTAL>555.0000</TOTAL>
        </row>
    </invoice_items>
</data>
```

**The jrxml sample**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Factura" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="153c2ff6-b65d-49fa-80de-5c1a093eafcc">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="FC_XML"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Factura_pozitii" uuid="1ee50e5a-b071-4886-8407-2ac843fb9ad1">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="FC_XML"/>
        <queryString language="XPath">
            <![CDATA[/data/invoice_items/row]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="ID_Invoice_Row" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="ID_Invoice_Row"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ID_Invoice_Row]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="Denumire" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="Denumire"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Denumire]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="Valoare" class="java.lang.Float">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="Valoare"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Valoare]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="VAT" class="java.lang.Float">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="VAT"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[VAT]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="TOTAL" class="java.lang.Float">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="TOTAL"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TOTAL]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="XPath">
        <![CDATA[/data/invoice]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Seller_Name" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="Seller_Name"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Seller_Name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="34" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="0" width="175" height="15" uuid="e9843cbc-f80d-4d43-ba3e-12abb7c1ed11"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Seller_Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="15" uuid="449ed594-81b1-420c-b361-55709bd951c7"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Seller name:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="92" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="60" uuid="93a83571-11ee-4173-9726-846f15cbdfec"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="Blank">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Factura_pozitii" uuid="8a5ec067-61b0-4580-8aee-4fe353996db3">
                        <datasetParameter name="XML_DATA_DOCUMENT">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_DATA_DOCUMENT}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="XML_INPUT_STREAM">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_INPUT_STREAM}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="XML_FILE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_FILE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="net.sf.jasperreports.xml.source">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{net.sf.jasperreports.xml.source}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="XML_DATE_PATTERN">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_DATE_PATTERN}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="XML_NUMBER_PATTERN">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_NUMBER_PATTERN}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="XML_LOCALE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_LOCALE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="XML_TIME_ZONE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_TIME_ZONE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="d360ed7c-1960-426e-8541-07a125682d7e">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="15">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="15" uuid="cdea816f-81e3-4b32-bec6-7791d9862c37"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="400" uuid="042fc8f1-a37e-412f-a4e8-f6f747d3054c">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="400" height="30" uuid="015596ef-4660-4c7f-9b6d-96b6ddf3858d"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Denumire]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="15">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="983e6d52-1734-4ace-b791-ec8cfc03cf7c"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Denumire}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="69c6f7bc-1e99-4ced-afcd-adfc2d8930a9">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="0aa9d86a-dda0-469d-9923-b3d1e996b583"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[valoare]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="15">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField pattern="#,##0.###">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="15" uuid="11006503-d218-4a64-b8d4-240f611c4727"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Valoare}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**The php code:**

```php
use PHPJasper\PHPJasper;

$input = '/your_input_path/your_report.jasper';
$output = '/your_output_path';
$data_file = __DIR__ . '/your_data_files_path/your_xml_file.xml';
$options = [
    'format' => ['pdf'],
    'params' => [],
    'locale' => 'en',
    'db_connection' => [
        'driver' => 'xml',
        'data_file' => $data_file,
        'xml_xpath' => '/data/invoice'
    ]
];

$jasper = new PHPJasper();

$jasper->process(
    $input,
    $output,
    $options
)->execute();
```

If I run in terminat it says:

> WARN JRXpathQueryExecuter:130 - No XML source was provided

I think it is for the second dataset, because the first is OK.

Comment: I edit in your jrxml (as required by Stack Overflow) removing some fields to minimize it.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in your jrxml you are expecting two datasources (1 for main, 1 for table), in fact this report will work for example in JasperSoft Studio defining a correct [data adapter](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v611/using-data-adapters-reports-and-datasets).

However lets find a solution using only 1 datasource as defined in your php code.

In jasper reports you can create a new datasource from an xml datasource by using [`subDataSource`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRXmlDataSource.html#subDataSource-java.lang.String-) in this case on main datasource.

> Creates a sub data source using the **current node** (record) as the root of the document. An additional XPath expression specifies the select criteria applied to this new document and that produces the nodes (records) for the data source.

**current node**, is bold because this is our first issue, your current main XPath query `/data/invoice` is too deep since we want to create a datasource on `data/invoice_items`

### Solution

1. Select only `data` in main XPath query both in php and jrxml.

   ```
   <queryString language="XPath">
       <![CDATA[/data]]>
   </queryString>
   ```
2. Adjust your main fields accordingly, you need to navigate down to `invoice` see `fieldDescription`.

   ```
   <field name="Seller_Name" class="java.lang.String">
       <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="Seller_Name"/>
       <fieldDescription><![CDATA[invoice/Seller_Name]]></fieldDescription>
   </field>
   ```
3. Create the `subDataSource` for the table

   ```
   <datasetRun subDataset="Factura_pozitii" uuid="8a5ec067-61b0-4580-8aee-4fe353996db3">
        .. params ..
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/data/invoice_items/row")]]></dataSourceExpression>
   </datasetRun>
   ```

**Complete jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Factura" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="153c2ff6-b65d-49fa-80de-5c1a093eafcc">
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Factura_pozitii" uuid="1ee50e5a-b071-4886-8407-2ac843fb9ad1">
        <queryString language="XPath">
            <![CDATA[/data/invoice_items/row]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="ID_Invoice_Row" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="ID_Invoice_Row"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ID_Invoice_Row]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="Denumire" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="Denumire"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Denumire]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="Valoare" class="java.lang.Float">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="Valoare"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Valoare]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="VAT" class="java.lang.Float">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="VAT"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[VAT]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="TOTAL" class="java.lang.Float">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="TOTAL"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TOTAL]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="XPath">
        <![CDATA[/data]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Seller_Name" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="Seller_Name"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[invoice/Seller_Name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="34" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="0" width="175" height="15" uuid="e9843cbc-f80d-4d43-ba3e-12abb7c1ed11"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Seller_Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="15" uuid="449ed594-81b1-420c-b361-55709bd951c7"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Seller name:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="92" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="60" uuid="93a83571-11ee-4173-9726-846f15cbdfec"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="Blank">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Factura_pozitii" uuid="8a5ec067-61b0-4580-8aee-4fe353996db3">
                        <datasetParameter name="XML_DATE_PATTERN">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_DATE_PATTERN}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="XML_NUMBER_PATTERN">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_NUMBER_PATTERN}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="XML_LOCALE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_LOCALE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="XML_TIME_ZONE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_TIME_ZONE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/data/invoice_items/row")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="d360ed7c-1960-426e-8541-07a125682d7e">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="15">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="15" uuid="cdea816f-81e3-4b32-bec6-7791d9862c37"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="400" uuid="042fc8f1-a37e-412f-a4e8-f6f747d3054c">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="400" height="30" uuid="015596ef-4660-4c7f-9b6d-96b6ddf3858d"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Denumire]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="15">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="983e6d52-1734-4ace-b791-ec8cfc03cf7c"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Denumire}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="69c6f7bc-1e99-4ced-afcd-adfc2d8930a9">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="0aa9d86a-dda0-469d-9923-b3d1e996b583"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[valoare]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="15">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField pattern="#,##0.###">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="15" uuid="11006503-d218-4a64-b8d4-240f611c4727"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Valoare}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I understand now. Datasource is /data and then fields are invoice/Seller_Name and invoice_items/row/Denumire. Thank you!

Comment: what is my XML has list of section with name attribute then how to select is as subDataSource?
Example: 
````<section name="valuation">
        <capital-value>
           some data
        </capital-value>
        <location>
           some data
        </location>
    </section>
    <section name="subject-property">
        <address>72 Gordon Avenue</address>
        <postcode>HA7 3QS</postcode>
        <bedrooms>2</bedrooms>
    </section>
````

Comment: @SanjaySahani it's not clear exactly what you need, but you use xpath query hence maybe something like `section[@name='valuation']`, but it better if you ask a new question with a full [mcve] including example of your actually xml and jrxml

Comment: @PetterFriberg thanks I just figured it and u explained the same thanks buddy

Comment: @PetterFriberg have a look at this problem. maybe it has a good reason to be explained.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407670/how-to-make-line-chart-in-jasper-report-as-xml-input