# How to fix "Field not found" error in case using two XPath expressions in single report?

Tags: xpath, charts, jasper-reports, linechart

I've been struggling with my problem since 7 days.
I have **1 XML** input data and want to convert that into desired **PDF** file with **line chart**

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sample-data xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:ht="urn:xyz.com/xslt/extensions">
<section name="relative-performance">
        <historic-valuations>
            <valuation-list>
                <valuation>
                    <value>890000</value>
                    <date>2014-12-01T00:00:00</date>
                </valuation>
                <valuation>
                    <value>923789</value>
                    <date>2015-12-01T00:00:00</date>
                </valuation>
                <valuation>
                    <value>897978</value>
                    <date>2016-12-01T00:00:00</date>
                </valuation>
                <valuation>
                    <value>957883</value>
                    <date>2017-12-01T00:00:00</date>
                </valuation>
                <valuation>
                    <value>919203</value>
                    <date>2018-12-01T00:00:00</date>
                </valuation>
                <valuation>
                    <value>950000</value>
                    <date>2019-12-01T00:00:00</date>
                </valuation>
            </valuation-list>
        </historic-valuations>
        <local-market-index>
            <local-market>HA7 3</local-market>
            <index-value-list>
                <index-value>
                    <value>890000</value>
                    <date>2014-12-01T00:00:00</date>
                </index-value>
                <index-value>
                    <value>931069</value>
                    <date>2015-12-01T00:00:00</date>
                </index-value>
                <index-value>
                    <value>912244</value>
                    <date>2016-12-01T00:00:00</date>
                </index-value>
                <index-value>
                    <value>980893</value>
                    <date>2017-12-01T00:00:00</date>
                </index-value>
                <index-value>
                    <value>948882</value>
                    <date>2018-12-01T00:00:00</date>
                </index-value>
                <index-value>
                    <value>988654</value>
                    <date>2019-12-01T00:00:00</date>
                </index-value>
            </index-value-list>
        </local-market-index>
    </section>
</sample-data>
```

**My JRXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.11.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.11.0-0c4056ccaa4d25a5a8c45672d2f764ea3498bebb  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f3e693aa-b906-4972-95b4-4a7430cabd45">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="NewData"/>
    <subDataset name="subData" uuid="87538cc6-4a9e-4953-acaa-3190030517a8">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="NewData"/>
        <queryString language="xPath">
            <![CDATA[/sample-data/section[@name='relative-performance']/historic-valuations/valuation-list/valuation]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="value" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="value"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[value]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="date" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="date"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[date]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/sample-data/section[@name='relative-performance']/local-market-index/index-value-listindex-value]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="value1" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="value1"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[value]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="date1" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="date1"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[date]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="370" splitType="Stretch">
            <lineChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="550" height="290" uuid="9bdc21fd-9b73-4ea9-919e-2c8807153f78"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset resetType="Report"/>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Estimated capital value"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{date}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA[""]]></labelExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Local market index"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{date1}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{value1}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA[""]]></labelExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <linePlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </linePlot>
            </lineChart>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I searched a lot and come to know that In my situation I need to make subDataSource so I did from
[How to use multiple xpath datasets on XML datasource using PHP Jasper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459716/how-to-use-multiple-xpath-datasets-on-xml-datasource-using-php-jasper/57475236?noredirect=1#comment106836962_57475236)

But I'm still getting this **error**

```
There are compilation error please fix the design 
Field not found:date ---net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression@95d1b2c
Field not found:date ---net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression@62032410
```

I want to make line chart in jasper report then make it pdf in java which is another part but main issue is I'm not able to make a desired **PDF** which is
[image: Desired graph I want]

Comment: Yes good question I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: Your template is not valid. The *subData* is not using at your report - the chart is using main datasource at your example. It means that you can use only fields from this main datasource. Single chart can't use several datasources.

Comment: @alex-k so how can I achieve that graph man?

Comment: To create a chart like that you need to create 1 data source that have it all, AFIK combining multiple datasources in chart will not work. With your current xml this seems very hard. My solution would have been to create a java class, that elaborates the xml and returns a correct JRDatasource or to return the chart directly from java.

Comment: @PetterFriberg can u provide any source which will demonstrate this because I not familiar eith jasper report tool to play with datasource as Bean

Comment: @PetterFriberg or suggest any other way to achieve the chart rather than jasper report

Comment: You need to develop in java, study how to parse xml in java and either create a JRDatasource or create the chart directly in java using JFreechart.